# Where exactly role based access control checks user's permissions in MVC pattern?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, rbac

I am implementing role-based access control in my simple PHP application. I am not using any frameworks. From the one hand, I have this essential for MVC pattern `Route` class, from another hand, I have `sidebar.php` file that contains links to all sections.

My rbac implementation: user->role->permission.So, each user will have many roles and every role will have plenty of permissions.

My task is that the user would be able to work with only allowed to its section on my website.

The question is where exactly I should check user's permissions?
One of the ideas is to show in `sidebar.php` only these sections which are allowed, but I don't feel good about this.

What's the way you usually use?

P.S.: Good article will help too.

Comment: Does my question make sense?

Comment: For me, the question makes sense and is a good one. A remark, though: You say _"One of the ideas is to show in sidebar.php only these sections which are allowed,..."_ . What exactly is in sidebar.php - I suppose only a menu? And what if, indeed, the user can not access a corresponding "restricted" menu entry in the sidebar, but still can juggle with the URI parts (known to her/him beforehand), in order to access the unauthorized server resources?... You might want to describe a bit better what you mean by that sentence.

Comment: @dakis Yes, correct. Inside `sidebar.php` only the menu of the website. Thnks, for the question, I didn't think about juggling with URL.

Comment: @tereško, thnx for clearing. Can you say on what stage you usually do user's permission checking?